# Как задать относительный путь до каталога в asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, asp.net

У меня есть каталог в котором лежат все папки и файлы проекта, такие как Views, controllers, web.config и т.д., в нём я создал папку blocks и хочу чтобы в эту папку у меня записывались файлы, но почему-то при записи у меня выдаётся исключение 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: "Не удалось найти часть пути "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express/blocks"." 
Я так понял, что за текущую директорию принимается та папка, из которой запускается сервер. Как мне получить путь к каталогу именно с ПРОЕКТОМ?

Вот как переменная с путём указана в коде:

```
Path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/blocks/";
```

Comment: Какая версия asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string blockPath = Server.MapPath("~/blocks/");
```

или

```
string blockPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/blocks/")
```